# Power Automate - Selecting from an array with multiple objects

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

New to Power Automate and I'm struggling with what seems to be a very small problem and likely be a doddle for someone to resolve:

I have an array that looks like this:

```
{
"index": 0,
"text": "Customer reference"
  },
  {
    "index": 1,
    "text": "Customer id"
  },
  {
    "index": 2,
    "text": "21009515004"
  },
  {
    "index": 3,
    "text": "Bill number"
  },
  {
    "index": 4,
    "text": "11023587"
  }
]
```

And I need to Select or assign to a variable the 'text' value where 'index' value is specified.

So I need the value "11023587" by selecting "index" = 4

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the switch method to achieve this，here is an example:

[image]
And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created a variable to store an array.

[image: Initialize variable action]

I can then use a Filter array action to find the object in the array that has index equal to 4. The expression shown in the screen capture is `item()['index']`.

[image: Filter action]

To get the output from the Filter array action you use the expression `body('Filter_array')`. This will be an array. To get the object from the array you use the expression `first(body('Filter_array'))`. Finally, to get the text property from the object you use the expression `first(body('Filter_array'))['text']`. You can get this value in the flow using a Compose action.

[image: Compose action]

I hope this helps.